# pagehide event doesn't work on Safari [IOS]

Tags: javascript, ios, html, events, safari

I want to use pagehide, like beforeunload on my website desktop version, but it doesn't fire on last ios Safari. I don't understand why. Can you help me ?

Thank's !

my Js code :

```
window.addEventListener( 'pagehide', function(ev) {
        if ($("#post_title")[0].value == "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/posts/<%=@post.id%>/session_add',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                }
            });
            return ev.returnValue = ' ';
        }
})
```

Comment: According to Apple's documentation you should use the `pagehide` event instead, not sure about the behaviour though, as Apple usually makes up their own rules to improve UX.

Comment: Yes, so it's why i don't understand it's not working

Comment: I think the time allowed to execute script is only 500ms, might also depend on the next page that is loading. AJAX requests most likely will never finish their request.

Comment: just this : ```window.addEventListener( 'pagehide', function(ev) {
        return ev.returnValue = ' ';
    })```

doesn't work too

Comment: @Js60, do you remember if your navigation was between pages on the same-site? I notice that chromium since version 69, changed its behavior and stop emitting pagehide (and pageshow) for navigations cross-site, or navigations from http to https and vice versa.